How to migrate the azure devops TFVC code from one org to another org with commits History?
I need to move the code from one org to another org with the commit history in TFVC (TFS). Also, the task related to it and board should be migrated. Can anyone help on this?
Note: It's TFVC (TFS) not azure git.
Need to move the TFVC (TFS) code with history

Does the destination organization already exist and does it already have a TFVC repo? An organization can have multiple git repos but only one TFVC repo. If you have two active organizations both with active TFVC repos, then your question is about combining one TFVC repo into another TFVC repo. If the destination organization exists but doesn't have a TFVC repo, then your question  might be about cloning the TFVC repo and attaching the clone to another organization, If the destination organization doesn't exist, then your question might be about cloning and renaming the organization.

There's really not a good mechanism to do that. The best option is to use the git-tfs tool, which is a two-way TFVC/Git bridge. So you convert source TFVC to Git, then play back the Git commits as TFVC changesets in the target system. However, it's not full fidelity. There are also third-party paid migration tools like OpsHub, but those tools are typically expensive and won't necessarily do the job better than git-tfs. You're just trying to do something that TFVC wasn't designed for, Azure DevOps wasn't designed for, and TFVC is long deprecated and no longer receiving investment.

Thanks for the clarification, @DanielMann. I used the git-tfs tool to move the code from one org (TFVC) to another org (git) with all the histories in it. Also, for moving the boards, I used Naked agility repo which helped me to move all the comments, attachments etc.
